# IntelliJ IDEA project files documentation

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a documentation on the format of IntelliJ IDEA project files (`.ipr`, `.iws`, `.iml`) anywhere? Couldn't find it on their website or in Google.
I am trying to do some automated project generation, and without the docs it's like reverse engineering, which is not really efficient.

Comment: There was a maven plugin for IDEA, (no longer maintained).  Maybe you could get some information from their code: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-idea-plugin-2.2.1/
or their site:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/index.html

Comment: @crea1 Thanks, that may be useful